# Reading Setting Not Working for Number of Posts

Tags: posts

I set the number of posts to show on my blog to 1, but the blog is showing all the posts I have. I tried to insert a custom query into my index.php, but it just made one post show up endlessly. This is my index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<div id="content" class="group">
    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

            <div id="post_column">

            <div class="post_entry group">

                <div class="post_header"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>

            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif;  ?>
</div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Likely, you have a plugin or theme code that is conflicting... perhaps something is filtering `pre_get_posts`. Try disabling plugins. Then try switching to a default theme to isolate the problem. You shouldn't need to manually set the `posts_per_page` as the option you've chose in the reading settings is the default for `WP_Query`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to edit your parent themes files as its bad practice.

You can use this code in your child themes functions file

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpsites_limit_posts' );
function wpsites_limit_posts( $query ) {

if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_home() ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '1' );

    }
}
```

Won't work when admin is logged in.

Change the is_home() [conditional tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to the archive you want to limit posts per page.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the blog page is not home, so then should I change "is_home" to something else?

Comment: Updated my answer. Mark this as the accepted answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Your posts page, according to your Reading Settings is your home page even if its not your front page.

Answer (score -1):

I'm newbie in WordPresss, but try to change your code to this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<div id="content" class="group">
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php $myQuery = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 1));
    while($posts_to_update ->have_posts()) : $posts_to_update ->the_post(); ?>

            <div id="post_column">
              <div class="post_entry group">
                <div class="post_header"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
              </div>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif;  ?>
</div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**UPDATE:**
Another solution is to add this code in functions.php :

```
if ( is_home() ) {
    // Display only 1 post for the original blog archive
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. About your updated solution-- the blog page is not home, so then should I change "is_home" to something else?

Comment: I don't know the structure of your theme, but copy it as is and write what is the result :)

Comment: I did, but the blog just shows all the posts.

Comment: if your blog page is a static page with template you could change is_home with is_page(PUT HERE THE ID OF THE PAGE)

Comment: I set the id like this '    if ( is_page(14) ) {
    // Display only 1 post for the original blog archive
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
    return;
}' but the blog shows everything.

Comment: Also, the blog page doesn't have a special template. It's a blog which is set to be the posts page in the reading setting.

Comment: I'm bit confused...Did you try to modify your index.php as in solution before update?

Comment: If I try the code before update, the page says "Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object in /homepages/2/d386670083/htdocs/us/wp-content/themes/artkapsule/index.php on line 9"